# android/phonegap Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'downloader' of undefined at file

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

```
$(document).ready(function() {
window.plugins.downloader.downloadFile("http://some_path/images/image1.jpg", {overwrite: true}, 
      function(res) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    }, function(error) {
        alert(error);
    }
); });
```

**Error:-
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'downloader' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:11**

i have included the correct js files and in proper order still i am getting this error...

I even tried replacing all calls to PhoneGap by cordova... still it gives the same error eg

```
cordova.addConstructor(function() {
cordova.addPlugin("Downloader", new Downloader());
//window.plugins.Downloader = new Downloader();
//PluginManager.addService("Downloader", "com.phonegap.plugins.downloader.Downloader"); 
});
```

Comment: What version of PhoneGap are you using?

Comment: using this `window.Downloader = new Downloader();`  in downloader.js and `window.Downloader.downloadFile("h`  in index.html gives another error : no method found for **Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Downloader> has no method 'downloadFile' at file:**

Answer (score 4):

If you closely observe the LogCat log, you will notice that there is an error in "downloader.js" file. It is made for older version of phonegap. I was searching a lot how to fix the same problem as yours but I only found your question posted here. So, the bottom line is that we'll have to fix the syntax in the script file. Those morons changed whole syntax without care of backward compatibility :(

In order to make the code working, replace the downloader.js code with this:

```
/* downloader.js */
function Downloader() {}
    Downloader.prototype.downloadFile = function(fileUrl, params, win, fail) {

    //Make params hash optional.
    if (!fail) win = params;
       cordova.exec(win, fail, "Downloader", "downloadFile", [fileUrl, params]);
};

if(!window.plugins) {
    window.plugins = {};
}
if (!window.plugins.Downloader) {
    window.plugins.Downloader = new Downloader();
}
```

And next, the call should be:

```
window.plugins.Downloader.downloadFile(url, {dirName: contentDirectory, fileName: someFileName, overwrite: true},
             function(data){
                 if(data=="exist"){
                  /// alert("File already exist");
                     console.log("File allready exist!");
                 }
                 else{
                     console.log("Status: " + data.status);
                 }
             },
             function(data){
                 console.log("error: "+data); 
             }
     );
```

Comment: I'm writing this after all night without sleep. There is no need for upload and download plugins, they implemented this in v. 2.1.0, please see their documentation. Another thing... it will not work with self-signed certificate!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it is actual since the phonegap implementation of download doesn't work well...

@Marjan: I tried to work with the phonegap implementation on PhoneGap 2.8.1. The best result I got was a working download, but all downloaded files had only 6 kilobyte and there was no error at all.

So... If anybody has an idea on the downloader plugin to get it to work (as described above), please let us know.

Comment: this may not be the answer you are looking for... But the same code snippet works on the earlier version i.e phonegap1.9...  I have no idea about the latest versions.